# Canonical question/answer for an out of place JavaScript callback

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

As we know, there is a [very good canonical target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for returning values from an asynchronous call.

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782988/issue-with-my-callback-function-it-is-not-waiting-for-its-parameter-before-bein) where the OP has included the necessary callback function, but called it in the wrong place.  I feel like this must also be a duplicate by now but couldn't find anything; I don't feel that it's *entirely* suitable to mark it as a dupe of the question mentioned above.

Is there a suitable, good quality, dupe target for such questions?  Or should we just aim them at the canonical one above?

Comment: Have you tried asking about this in the js chat? You would have a more targeted audience there

Comment: @codeMagic No - didn't even cross my mind.  Will give it a go later, thanks!

Comment: I just dropped this post in there for them. Figured they missed me anyway

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks - believe the chat subdomain is blocked where I am at the mo...

Comment: Coming from the JS room. This is a problem of the type "silly error -- op being stupid" and should have it's own close vote reason, IMHO. We get such questions in chat and sometimes we help and sometimes leave it. Nothing much can be done with a canonical here I think.

Answer (score 1):

That case seems like a simple bug to me. Not simple enough to be closed as a typo, but just a flaw in the logic.

When and where callbacks ought to be called varies pretty widely, so a canonical for "mistakes related to callbacks" would be... broad, at best. Not sure how much value folks would get out of it.